# array_name.className gives "className is null or not an object" in IE

Tags: javascript

I am using jQuery Datatables plugin for displaying data.
This works perfectly in Mozilla and Chrome but in IE, it produces 
"className is null or not an object" error at the following line
of code in jQuery.Datatables.js

**Code:**
if ( nTds[i].className.indexOf(sClass+"1") != -1 )
{
    for ( j=0, jLen=(nTds.length/iColumns) ; j

I am not sure if the problem pertains to "indexOf" or "className"
as IE does not support indexOf

Any help on this issue would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The object itself is problematic... naturally the property will as well.

I used:

```
if(typeof nTds[i] != 'undefined' && typeof nTds[i] !=null && typeof nTds[i] !='null')
{
   // original className check code in here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an element that does not have a `className` property defined. Do a type check before the indexOf check.

```
if(typeof nTds[i].className != 'undefined' && nTds[i].className.indexOf(sClass+"1") != -1) { ...
```

EDIT:

Try this code exactly.

```
    if(typeof nTds[i].className != 'undefined') {
        if ( nTds[i].className.indexOf(sClass + "1") != -1) { 
            for ( j=0, jLen=(nTds.length/iColumns) ; j<jLen ; j++ ) { 
                nTds[(iColumns*j)+i].className = $.trim( nTds[(iColumns*j)+i].className.replace( sClass+"1", "" ) ); 
            } 
        } else if ( nTds[i].className.indexOf(sClass+"2") != -1 ) { 
            for ( j=0, jLen=(nTds.length/iColumns) ; j<jLen ; j++ ) { 
                nTds[(iColumns*j)+i].className = $.trim( nTds[(iColumns*j)+i].className.replace( sClass+"2", "" ) ); 
            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That did not fix the issue. Now it says 'undefined' is null or not an object. I tried to do an alert for nTds[i].className just before the if condition which was displaying nothing

Comment: if (typeof nTds[i].className != 'undefined' && nTds[i].className.indexOf(sClass + "1") != -1)
      {
       for ( j=0, jLen=(nTds.length/iColumns) ; j<jLen ; j++ )
       {
        nTds[(iColumns*j)+i].className = 
         $.trim( nTds[(iColumns*j)+i].className.replace( sClass+"1", "" ) );
       }
      }

Comment: Perform the same type check in your else-if-statement before this code snippet: nTds[i].className.indexOf(sClass+"2") != -1

Comment: or wrap all of that logic in a if(typeof nTds[i].className != 'undefined') { ... your code ...}

Comment: Sorry to bother you again ... I tried the second option, but still gives "undefined is null or not an object"

Comment: I've added an edit to my answer. It's 2 am here and I have to get some sleep, I'm sorry =/. You might also do a check on this part of the code as well: nTds[(iColumns*j)+i] as this could return an object that does not have the `className` property.

Comment: Did you do a check on nTds[(iColumns*j)+i] to see if it exists before you try and modify/use it?

Answer (score 0):

Basically the same as Danial's answer, but it's no need to explictly check for `undefined`:

```
if ( nTds[i].className && nTds[i].className.indexOf(sClass+"1") != -1 ) { ...
```